# Use directive in host of another Directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I want to add a directive to an element from another directive by using the host property, but there doesn't seem to be a way to reference the other directive.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[one]',
    host: { '[two]': '"some-value"' }
    // How can I reference DirectiveTwo here?
})
export class DirectiveOne { }

@Directive({
    selector: '[two]'
})
export class DirectiveTwo { }
```

When doing this, I get the standard "Can't bind to 'two' since it isn't a known native property" error.

What is the correct way of referencing and using one directive from another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can now be achieved with `hostDirectives` in Angular v15+

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '...',
  hostDirectives: [Tooltip, Menu],
})
export class MenuWithTooltip { }
```

Details in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/directive-composition-api#adding-directives-to-a-component)

Answer (score 16):

Directives are instantiated by Angular for selectors matching statically added HTML (element, id, attribute, class, ...) only.
There is no way to instantiate directives using the `host` parameter of the `@Component()` or `@Directive()` decorator. There is also no way to create directives dynamically using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` (former `DynamicComponentLoader`)

Getting a reference to another directive that was instantiated by Angular because of a statically added HTML on the same element is supported though.

Comment: If that is so, what is the best practice for having one Directive extend or use the functionality of others? This seems like a pretty significant limitation.

Comment: I think this is a topic for a bigger update https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11606