# Angular 2 add directive based on a binding

Tags: angular

I have a DraggableDropZone directive which handles items being dropped on to it. I would like to set this directive on my component based on a boolean flag.  Basically sometimes the component needs to be a drop target and sometimes it does not.  Attribute binding does not seem to work.

Doesn't work:

```
<div [attr.DraggableDropZone]="DropZone"></div>
```

If I simply do this it works, so I know my directive is good:

```
<div DraggableDropZone></div>
```

So I need 'DraggableDropZone' to be added conditionally at runtime.

Comment: Update: It looks like this is just not supported: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148080/use-angular2-directive-in-host-of-another-directive)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an input parameter and then control the behaviour in your DraggableDropZone directive:

```
<div [DraggableDropZone]="enabled"></div>
```

and

```
@Input('DraggableDropZone') enabled: boolean;
```

Comment: I had tried that before but didn't think it was supported. I am getting: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'DraggableDropZone' since it isn't a known property of 'div'