# Whole mat-dialog becomes drag handle when using cdk drag-drop

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I was trying to combine `mat-dialog` and `drag-drop` in Angular Material 9.
The `dialog.html` is:

```html
<h1 mat-dialog-title cdkDrag cdkDragHandle cdkDragRootElement=".cdk-overlay-pane">
Title</h1>
<div>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-stroked-button (click)="onExit()">Exit</button>
</div>
```

But it seems that the whole dialog becomes the drag handle instead of just the `dialog-title` part.

stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-putdym

Could someone please give a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here `cdkDragRootElement=".cdk-overlay-pane"`

You are telling it that the root element to drag is the entire overlay pane (by specifying the class).

Just remove that line and it will default to the element it is on, or specify the class for the title `cdkDragRootElement=".mat-dialog-title"`. Either will work. The function of that directive is so you can put a smaller drag handle that drags a larger parent element.

Edit: I misunderstood what the desired functionality was, the solution is to basically seperate the cdkDrag directive and cdkDragHandle directive to different elements. Here is a modified version of your stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ucdjl3

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually have tried that before, but in that case the only movable part is the dialog part. What I was trying to do is to make the title a handle to move the whole dialog. It seems that the ```transform``` is set to the element with ```drag``` attribute. Will try to find a way to bind that to the ```.cdk-overlay-pane```.

Comment: I miss understood what your goal was, updating my answer for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the perfect anwser!